# Oracle equivalence classes not working in regular expressions

Tags: regex, oracle, nls

The following Oracle equivalence class regular expression:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('eéëèÉËÈE' '[[=É=]]+') FROM dual;
```

is supposed to return:

```
eéëèÉËÈE
```

but instead it returns:

```
É
```

I've also tried putting the following in front of it:

```
alter session set NLS_SORT=GENERIC_BASELETTER;
alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE=FRENCH;
```

Anyone have any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83c37/8

Are you sure your original query uses `[[=É=]]` instead of `[=É=]`?

Answer (score 0):

`[=eéëèÉËÈE=]+`

http://regexr.com?33330

`É` is not going to match the other letters.